# Manage collections in JPA 2.x

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb

Could you advice me what is the best way to update OneToMany relationship using JPA? Now in my application I make the following:

1. Create new entity (Offer) and persist in db (first EJB transaction - using OfferService.update method)
2. Delete and add some objects to the entity child collection (in JSF managed bean)
3. In the second EJB transaction EntityManager.merge(entity).

**Main problem**:
- orphanRemoval not work (child orphans remain in the db).

Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "OFFER")
public class Offer extends AbstractEntity {
    // ...
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "offer", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<OfferPosition> offerPositions = new HashSet<OfferPosition>();
    // ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "OFFER_POSITION")
public class OfferPosition extends AbstractEntity {    
    // ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "OFFER_ID", nullable = false)
    private Offer offer;
    // ...
}
```

Delete OfferPosition (in JSF Managed Bean):

```
public void delete(OfferPosition position) {
    this.offer.getOfferPositions().remove(position);
    position.setOffer(null);
}
```

Update Offer (in EJB):

```
public class OfferService {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public Offer update(Offer offer) {
        if (offer.getId() == null) {
            em.persist(offer);
            return offer;
        }
        return em.merge(offer);
    }    
}
```

Comment: You should post the entities, at least the properties with the mapping annotations. You also hastily brush over a "second transaction", so you should also post the code that does the loading and the mutating.

Comment: @Gimby thank you for tips. I updated my post.

Comment: Snippets don't really work, they hide too much details. Try to paint a more complete picture that shows how all the bits are wired together. Most questions can't really be answered without an [mcve].

Comment: I really dont know what I should add. I dont get any exception. Maybe do you know which areas of the app I should inspect closer?